# What the expression of a one-dimensional representation of $H$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

Let $G= \{ g=(x,y,t); \quad x,y,t \in \mathbb R\}$ be the Heisenberg group and $H= \{ g=(x,y,t) \in G; \quad x=0\}= \{ h=(0,y,t); \quad y,t \in \mathbb R\}$ be a subgroup of $G$.

I want to know why the one-dimensional representation of $H$ is given by $$ \pi_{\lambda}(h) =\pi_{\lambda}(0,y,t)= e^{i\lambda \, t} $$
for a fixed $\lambda \in \mathbb R^{*}$, and it is not 
$$ \pi_{\lambda}(h) = e^{i\lambda \, y} \, ?$$
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, your second character is not equivalent to the previous one. However, there are more one-dimensional unitary representations (characters) of $H$.

Note that $H\simeq \mathbb R^2$ given by $(0,y,t)\mapsto (y,t)$. 
Hence, $\widehat H\simeq \widehat {\mathbb R^2}\simeq \mathbb R^2$. 
This last isomorphism is given by $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2\mapsto \sigma_{(a,b)}$ given by 
$$
\sigma_{(a,b)}(y,t)= e^{i(ay+bt)}.
$$